# How to display checkboxes in a function

Tags: php, html

In code below, by using implode and explode and by finding the option type for each question, I try to retrieve each individual option from the full option type.

So for example:

`A-E` makes `A B C D E`

`A-C` makes `A B C`

`True or False` makes `True False`

`Yes or No` makes `Yes No`

Now this works with the code below:

```
<?php

  function ExpandOptionType($option) { 
      $options = explode('-', $option);
      if(count($options) > 1) {
        $start = array_shift($options);
        $end = array_shift($options);
        do {
          $options[] = $start;
        }while(++$start <= $end);
      }
      else{
        $options = explode(' or ', $option);
      }
      return implode(" ", $options);
    }

foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {

    ?>

    <div class='lt-container'>

    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionNo[$key]) . ": " .  htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionContent[$key]); ?></p>



    <p><?php echo ExpandOptionType(htmlspecialchars($arrOptionType[$key])); ?></p>


    </div>


    <?php

    }

    ?>
```

But what I want to do is that except just displaying the individual options just by string, I want to display them as checkboxes. But my attempt below did not work, how can I get the checkboxes to be displayed? I'm actually getting a warning stating: `Warning: explode() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in ... on line 241`

```
 function ExpandOptionType($option) { 
        $options = explode('-', '<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"anstype\" class=\"answers\" id=\"answer".$option."\" name=\"answerName[$option]\" value=\"$option\" />', $option);
 //LINE 241
      if(count($options) > 1) {
        $start = array_shift($options); 
        $end = array_shift($options);
        do {
          $options[] = $start;
        }while(++$start <= $end);
      }
      else{
          $options = explode(' or', '<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"anstype\" class=\"answers\" id=\"answer".$option."\" name=\"answerName[$option]\" value=\"$option\" />', $option);

      }
      return implode(" ", $options);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you evern understand how [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) works?

Comment: @Kolink Explode is suppose to take out the - in between the options. Im assuming I do not put the checkbox in there?

Comment: @Kolink Im assuming I put the checkboxes in another php variable and where shall I place it, in the do {} or do I just put it underneath the `$options = explode...`?